# How do I change permission of /etc/sudoers to 440 in aws ec2 using terminal

Tags: amazon-ec2, user-permissions

I am trying to login as a super user in amazon ec2, but I see some error that

sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is world writable

sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable

sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting

sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

I tried using pkexec chmod 440 /etc/sudoers

but pkexec command is not found.

Please can anyone help me with this...

Thanks.

Comment: The same question appears to have been answered on serverfault:
http://serverfault.com/questions/392977/broke-my-etc-sudoers-file-on-amazon-ec2